How can I pass JWT to VectorSearchClient in Databricks without expiration?
I am looking to create a search vector retriever in databricks by using the following logic
vsc = VectorSearchClient(
    workspace_url=DATABRICKS_HOST,
    personal_access_token=get_access_token(),
    )

The get_access_token() function looks like the following
import constants as con

def get_access_token():
    """
    Creates a databricks access token from a client id and client secret.

    :return: databricks access token
    """
    CLIENT_ID = con.CLIENT_ID
    CLIENT_SECRET = con.CLIENT_SECRET

    # Token endpoint URL
    token_endpoint_url = con.TOKEN_ENDPOINT_URL

    # Prepare the data payload
    data = {"grant_type": "client_credentials", "scope": "all-apis"}

    # Make the POST request with Basic Authentication
    response = requests.post(
    token_endpoint_url, data=data, auth=(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET)
    )

    # Check if the request was successful
    if response.status_code == 200:
        # Parse the JSON response
        token_info = response.json()
        access_token = token_info.get("access_token")
        return access_token
    else:
        print("Error:", response.status_code)
        print("Response:", response.text)
        return None

However, when I pass the retriever to my MLFlow experiment and create a serving endpoint in Databricks the token expires after 1 hour and I can not query the endpoint anymore.
Is there a solution to dynamically create the token? For this project I unfortunately need a token setup like this and cannot use keys.

Do you need expire time more than one hour?

Provided solution below, check if it is working or not.

According to this documentation, the token expires in one hour, need to create another token after it expires.
So, alternative approach is to programmatically you store the expiration time globally and check every time you use it, generate new token if it expired else use the current one.
Code
import requests
import time

_access_token = None
_token_expiration = 0

def get_access_token():
    """
    Creates a databricks access token from a client id and client secret.

    :return: databricks access token
    """

    global _access_token, _token_expiration

    if _access_token and time.time() < _token_expiration:
        print("using current token")
        return _access_token

    CLIENT_ID = "<client_id>"
    CLIENT_SECRET = "<seceret>"
    workspace_url = "<url>"

    
    token_endpoint_url = f'{workspace_url}/oidc/v1/token'

    
    data = {"grant_type": "client_credentials", "scope": "all-apis"}

    
    response = requests.post(
    token_endpoint_url, data=data, auth=(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET)
    )

    if response.status_code == 200:
        token_info = response.json()
        _access_token = token_info.get("access_token")
        expires_in = token_info.get("expires_in", 3600)
        _token_expiration = time.time() + expires_in - 60
        print("Generated new token")
        return _access_token
    else:
        print("Error:", response.status_code)
        print("Response:", response.text)
        return None

By using above code, you can generate token dynamically every time when it is expired.
